# Symfony2. Twig: Doesn't work logic function when date variable changes

Tags: twig

```
{% set event_date = event.schedule|date('d-m-y') %}
{% set nowdate = "now"|date('d-m-y') %}
{% if event_date < nowdate %}
    view some 1
{% else %}
    view some 2
{% endif %}
```

If change *event_date* bigger or lower than *nowdate*, have one result: *view some 2*.
Why doesn't work?

Comment: seems you are compating two strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a string comparison situation. For better approach this, use the U filter as follow:

```
{% set event_date = event.schedule|date('U') %}
{% set nowdate = "now"|date('U') %}
{% if event_date < nowdate %}
    view some 1
{% else %}
    view some 2
{% endif %}

{{ event_date }}
```

Live testing in this [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/eo5kv0).

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing strings. `d-m-y` is not a usable format for comparing dates. Try `Y-m-d`, where the parts are in order of importance.

Even better, you could compare two `\DateTime` objects instead of strings. I assume `event.schedule` is one, you just need to pass one for the current date to twig.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [date filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html), Twig defines a [date() function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/date.html) which has been designed precisely to compare dates.